# Telex and Mumble

Tags: wireless

I am trying to make a Telex MP 2002 interact with a Mumble client for a homegrown production intercom. However, when everything is hooked up, whenever something plays on the computer, it is instantly echoed back by the Telex. Is there any way around this?

Edit

Ok, so this is connected via the 9 pin program input port on the back(input on channel two, but that doesn't matter because the system is in combine). The output is taken from the PA output onto the line level input on the computer. The problem that we are seeing is that when we adjusted the volume on that computer and it made the noise to show what volume it is at, it started echoing that sound, getting progressively louder.

Comment: Theatre intercom pumped to wireless chat room as a stand in for $2000 headsets. People that work in theatre sound design would know about a Telex/Clearcom intercom.

Comment: Can you add some more detail about how you are trying to use it and how you have wired it in?  There isn't really enough detail to answer it at the moment.

Comment: Added the information requested.